# Change image in APK file

Tags: android, reverse-engineering

I have an APK file. My source code is deleted because my hard drive has crashed. I want to change an image in that APK. My app is developed with Java.
Is it possible to do so? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have access to your keystore but you can use this tool to reverse engineer your apk. https://github.com/skylot/jadx